# How can get the series of $\log(x/(x-1))$ at $x=\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

When I used the Wolfram to give me the Taylor series of $\log(x/(x-1))$, I was amazed of the result. The Wolfram give me a Laurent series at $x=\infty$ as follow
$$\log(\frac{x}{x-1})=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{1}{3x^2}+...$$
So I wanted to check this solution by myself, but I don't know how to built this series at $x=\infty$ by using Laurent method. Any help

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $\;x\leftrightarrow\frac1x\;$ and doing the development around zero, you get

$$\frac x{x-1}\leftrightarrow\frac1{1-x}\implies \log\frac1{1-x}=-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$

and now go back $\;\frac1x\leftrightarrow x\;$ and get what is written there

Comment: What is the $x_1$

Comment: @Easy A typo, of course. Corrected now.

Comment: thanks,but I don't know if this Laurent method ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you call "the Laurent Method" to, but this goes both as Taylor or Laurent series at infinity, since this last is clearly not a point though "around it" we can develop some functions. Anyway, doing the inversion $\;x\leftrightarrow \frac1x\;$ and developing around zero is what is usually done. In fact, I don't know any other way to do something like this.